# Defining a special case of a subset-sum with complications

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I have a problem that I have a number of questions about. First, I'm mostly looking for help describing and understanding the problem at hand. Solutions are always welcome, but most importantly I could use some advice from someone more experienced than I. Now, to the problem at hand:

I have a set of orders that each require some number of items. I also have several groupings of items that each contain some number of some items (call them groups). The goal is to find a subset of the orders that can be fulfilled using as few groups as possible and where the total number of items contained within the orders is between n and N.

Edit: The constraints on the number of items contained in the orders (n and N) are chosen independently.

To me at least, that's a really complicated way of saying the problem so I've been trying to re-phrase it as a knapsack problem (I suspect this might reduce to a subset-sum). To help my conceptual understanding of this I've started using the following definitions:

- First, lets say that a dimension exists for each possible item, and somethings 'length' in that dimension is the number of that particular type of item it either has or requires.
- From this, an order becomes an 'n-dimensional object' where its value in each dimension corresponds to the number of that item that it requires.
- In addition, a group can be seen as an 'n-dimensional box' that has space in each dimension corresponding to the number of items it provides.
- An objects value is equal to the sum of its length in all dimensions.
- Boxes can be combined.

Given the above I've rephrased the problem to this:

- What is the smallest combination of boxes that can hold a combination of items with value between n and N.

**Question #1:** Is this a correct/useful way to express the problem? Does it seem like I've missed anything obvious?

As I see it, since there are two combinations that I'm looking for I need to break the problem into two parts. So far I think breaking the problem up like this is a good step:

1. How many objects can box (or combination of boxes) X hold?
2. Check all (or preferably some small subset of) the possible combinations of boxes and pick the 'best'.

That makes it a little more manageable, but I'm still struggling with the details.

**Question #2:** **Solved** To solve the first part I think it's appropriate to say that the cost of an object is equal to the sum of its length in all dimensions, so is it's value. That places me into a subset-sum problem, right? Obviously it's a special case, but does this problem have a name?

**Question #3:** **Solved** I've been looking into subset-sum solutions a lot, but I don't understand how to apply them to something like this in multiple dimensions. I assume it's been done before, but I'm unsure where to start my research. Could someone either describe the principles at work or point me in a research direction?

**Edit:** After looking at everyone's feedback and digging into the terms I think I've found a good algorithm I can implement to solve part 1. Since I will have a very large number of dimensions compared to the number of items it looks like using a 'primal effective capacity heuristic ([PECH](http://www.sci.wsu.edu/math/faculty/lih/MDKP.pdf))' will be a good fit. I'd be interested in hearing someones thoughts about it if they have experience with such an algorithm.

**Question #4:** For the second part, performance is a concern and I doubt it will be realistic to brute force it. So I intend to treat all combinations of boxes as a really big tree of solutions. The idea is to compute part 1 for all combinations of M-1 boxes where M is the total number of boxes. Somehow determine the 'best' couple box combinations from that set and do the same to their child nodes on the tree. Does this sound like it would help me arrive at something close to optimal? How would I choose the 'best' box combinations?

Thanks for reading! Suggestions for edits and clarifications are welcome.

Comment: It's not clear whether the optimality criterion is the number of orders that can be fulfilled, or the number of "groups" needed to fulfil them.  Suppose you have 1000 orders, and you can fulfil 800 of them using just 5 groups.  If you could fulfil 900 of them but this would require 6 groups, is this better or not?

Comment: The goal is to have a combination of orders that in total contain a number of items between two numbers, n and N, and contains the least number of groups. n and N are chosen completely independent from the problem at hand. If the 800 orders contained more than n items, but less than N, then it would be better than the 900 combination of orders.

Comment: I see.  And what are the typical sizes of all these things (orders, items in groups, number of groups)?

Comment: Most of the published exact algorithms for multidimensional knapsack are branch and bound. You could wade in to this space by experimenting with a mixed integer programming formulation/solver.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - A typical setup would have a total of 10,000-20,000 items needed by about 500-3,000 orders and contained in 10-20 groups.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat After googling those terms I'll definitely look into a BB approach. So far I've been assuming that I'll need an approximate solution given the sizes I'm working with so I haven't done much research on exact solutions. Thanks!

Comment: One thing that might help is that your problem sounds like Set Cover, which is NP-Complete, so yes, it does reduce to subset sum.